# Printer doesn't print until week later

Tags: router, printing

Whenever I try and print something, I shows up in the print queue but nothing happens. A week later after restarting multiple times, it prints all the things it has refused to print the rest of the week. The printer connects to the router (wired) and my computer connects to the router as well. Interestingly enough, if I send my files to my sister's computer (right next to it, also wired) her computer prints immediately. Does anyone know why this could be happening, or how I could fix it? Thank you.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Windows 7, the printer is an EPSON XP-410